# 502 Bad Gateway when connecting to SurrealDB on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, surrealdb

I'm following SurrealDB's guide to [Deploy on GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine)](https://docs.surrealdb.com/docs/deployment/google/#deploy-surrealdb)

When I try to connect the first time to set the root password I get an 502 error:

Every step before was successful.

```bash
$ surreal sql -e http://1.2.3.4   # timestamps are omitted
ERROR surreal::cli: There was a problem with the database:
 There was an error processing a remote HTTP request: 
 HTTP status server error (502 Bad Gateway) for url (http://1.2.3.4/health)

# timestamps are omitted
```

I confirmed I got an IP address:

```bash
$ kubectl get ingress surrealdb-tikv
NAME             CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
surrealdb-tikv   <none>   *       1.2.3.4   80      3h5m
```

Those logs seem fine:

```
$ kubectl logs surrealdb-tikv-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx
INFO surreal::env: Running 1.1.0+20240109.05682e3 for linux on x86_64
WARN surreal::dbs: ❌ IMPORTANT: Authentication is disabled. This is not recommended for production use. ❌
INFO surrealdb::kvs::ds: Connecting to kvs store at tikv://sdb-datastore-pd:2379
INFO surrealdb::kvs::ds: Connected to kvs store at tikv://sdb-datastore-pd:2379
INFO surrealdb::node: Started node agent
INFO surrealdb::net: Started web server on 0.0.0.0:8000

# timestamps are omitted
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: How is port 8000 being mapped to port 80?

Comment: @JohnHanley that should be the loadbalancer

Comment: Sorry, I meant to show the configuration of how the port is being mapped.

Comment: @JohnHanley To be honest, I don't know. I just followed the linked guide. There is no mention about a specific port mapping. The used configuration files don't include '80' neither

Comment: What is the value of `SURREALDB_URL`? As the example shows, you are not using the value. Instead, you are using `IP:PORT`. Try the example under `Deploy SurrealDB` Step 4. `Connect to the cluster and define the initial credentials:`

Comment: @JohnHanley The value of `SURREALDB_URL` is `http://1.2.3.4` which I used in the first code block

Comment: @JohnHanley the actual IP is changed of course.